# jQuery hide parent with all of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete parent element with all of its children after one of the child is actually clicked on
HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <span class='content' id='1'>Lorem</span>
    <span class='content' id='2'>Ipsum</span>
    <span class='content' id='3'>Dolor</span>
    <span class='content' id='4'>Sit</span>
    <span id='delete'>Delete</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).siblings("#1").text();
  var surname = $(this).siblings("#2").text();
  var add = $(this).siblings("#3").text();
  var all = $(this).siblings("#4").text();
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      'name': name,
      'surname': surname,
      'add': add,
      'all': all
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(this).siblings().remove(); // context of 'this' lost? doesnt work
      $(this).parent().remove();

    }
  });
});
```

Bear in mind. There is a few of those elements with class `container` having the exact same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value of `this` in a variable outside of the success callback scope.

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
  var self = this;
  // ...

  $.ajax({
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      $(self).siblings().remove();
      $(self).parent().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

It's worth pointing out that removing the parent element will also remove all of the children elements anyways. This means that you don't have to remove the sibling elements before removing the parent element.

```
$(self).parent().remove(); // No need to remove siblings, they will be removed.
```

However, you may want to remove the sibling elements, and then unwrap the element. In doing so, you can preserve the `#delete` element (if that's what you're trying to do).

```
$(self).siblings().remove();
$(self).unwrap();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I want to remove everything, so `$(self).parent().remove();` with storing the value of $(this) works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#delete").click(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  //Other code
  $.ajax({
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      elem.siblings().remove();
      elem.closest(".container").remove();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this

```
 $(".content").children().hide();
```

Comment: Hide is not removing/deleting  the elemnts

Comment: Since there is many more elements with `content` class. I'd unintentionally hide all of them.